# web based report generation that supports R (or just external programs)

Tags: r, report, reporting

I'm getting quite good at generating one off reports using R / Sweave / Knitr to process a template with R code that gets database data and produces a pdf / html / text / md or odf file, and I'm providing them more and more to users.

Ideally I'd love to provide an easy way for users to request a particular template with particular settings, then pick up the results of that report.

Can anyone suggest something like this, web based or whatever that will support an R / sweave workflow ??

Edit:  Generating these reports (sweave'ing or knit'ting) can take a while, 3-5 mins, so support for requesting and later pickup is a must.  In addtion multi user support would be good (i.e Bob can't see Jane's reports)

Comment: There is an excellent free report writer called `ireport` and you can use `PLR` in `postgresql` to execute R code against the database... however that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk do you want that your users design the template or juste they choose from a list of pre-defined templates?

Comment: @agstudy Just to pick from a list

Answer (score 1):

If you want a true, interactive, web-based R framework, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at RStudio's new app: [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/).

If you actually just want static reports of the PDF/HTML variety, I don't know that you need much to get that off the ground. You're basically just looking to take form-based input from a web page, pass that to R, run your reports, and offer the file as a download.

- To build a simple HTML form, PHP would be dead-simple and supported by most hosting providers.
- Then use something like PHP's `system()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) to call your RScript code passing the parameters in that call.
- In R, use the `commandArgs()` function to extract the parameters specified to your script, generate the report.
- Offer the generated report to the web user.

If you wanted something more comprehensive, you can look at setting up RApache or a similar technology, but I really think with the amount of effort you'd expend setting that up, you (and your users) would probably be better off using Shiny and getting the benefits of interactivity.

Comment: I have looked at Shiny, and it does tick some boxes.  unfortunatley generating these reports can take a considerable time (3-5mins) and a possible requirement may be multi user support.